# Pause and resume background music, while other playing in between

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, background-music

My scene has a background music played, when paused another music stars, but when resumed again I would like to finish the previous background music where it was left off.

As I understand, dension enables only 1 background music to be loaded at a time, so pause/resume background music will not work.

is there a way to remember the position of a track and then rewind it to that position?

Comment: You might want to add some more details on anything you've tried already and where you read that fact about only playing 1 background music at a time to show some more effort

Comment: also, I don't know enought to help you, but this link looks like it maybe useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906141/game-music-does-not-resume-when-the-player-returns-to-the-game-after-turning-off?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you reading the LearningCocos2d book , if you just want to solve your problem go right to the game manager + simple game audio engine section . 
It's a helper class that can easily alternate between sound fxs, backgrounds , etc.